# How to get pps and sps in ffmpeg 's h264 decoder

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I  encode the image for use video capturer and encode it in h264 by ffmpeg and sent to my client pc .

my client pc decode it and display it . It can be decoded and display well.

But I  save these compressed image in a file . and it can be decoded by vlc or quicktime. But It can be decoded by ffplay

I think because i did n't save the pps and sps info .

there is someone know how to get the pps  sps in ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't save the sps and pps, it wouldn't be decodable at all, by anyone. Something else could  be wrong. What command lines are you using to save the file and to play it?